# Define complement of a graph with use of adjacency graph

Tags: graph-theory

Lets take graph G:
[Graph G](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUvl0.png)
With adjacency matrix:
[Adjacency matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyofK.png)
How to calculate adjacency matrix of it's complement graph?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

What is the defining property of the adjacency matrix? What is the defining property of the complement graph? Can you translate the latter into the former?

Comment: Got it. Adjancet edges in graph G are non adjancet in complement and opposite. Only main diagonal stays the same. I don't know how I didn't see that earlier.

Comment: how is this an answer?